# Timer is not getting reset using clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, timer

This is my Timer function

```
var myTimer = setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();

    var seconds = d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds();
    var fiveMin = 60 * 5;
    var timeleft = fiveMin - seconds % fiveMin;
    var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + timeleft % 60;
    //console.log(result);
    var timerObj = {
        timer : result
    }
    $scope.timerArray = timerObj;
    $scope.$apply();

    if (timeleft === 1) { 
        $scope.statusDetails = [];
        $scope.timeDetails();
        $scope.get_dbStatus();                  
    }

}, 1000);
```

This function will reset the above timer when I click a button.

```
$scope.refreshStatusList = function(){
    $scope.hide = true;
    $scope.$emit('LOAD');
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    $scope.statusDetails = [];
    $scope.timeDetails();
    $scope.get_dbStatus();  
};
```

This is my refresh button in html page upon clicking it the timer must get reset.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <a href="#" title="Refresh" ng-click="refreshStatusList();">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you put together an example that we can run using the stackoverflow snippet editor or JSFiddle? I'd do it myself but I don't quite know if extra stuff is needed to setup angular

Comment: What is the value of `myTimer` before you call `clearInterval` ?

Comment: Why don't you use $interval. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9v45oa3g/1 - The refresh is stopping the timer

Comment: so what is the problem - can you recreate your problem using the jsfiddle and share its link

Comment: but when i click refresh button it should get reset to again 5:0

Comment: please help me in this regard

Answer (score 2):

Since, you are using [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs), You should use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) directive, which will internally call `$scope.apply()`

*Usage*

```
$scope.intervalPromise = $interval(function () {
    //Your code
}, 1000);
```

*To clear interval*

```
$interval.cancel($scope.intervalPromise);
```

Comment: by using $interval.cancel($scope.intervalPromise) it stops the timer rather than resetting it.

Comment: I want to get it reseted

Comment: jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9v45oa3g/1

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$scope.apply();
```

Comment: can you be more elaborate?